# FreeRADIUS authentication requests not being logged to the specified file

Tags: authentication, logging, freeradius

I'm setting up a new FreeRADIUS v3.0.20 system (Ubuntu 20.04) and having a problem getting auth requests to go to a separate file.  I was successful doing it on my older (v2.2.8) system but am apparently missing something here.  I checked the documentation, ran both systems in debug mode, but no luck.

I added the "requests..." line to the log section of /etc/freeradius/3.0/radiusd.conf

```
log {
        destination = files
        file = ${logdir}/radius.log
        requests = ${logdir}/radiusd-%{%{Virtual-Server}:-DEFAULT}-%Y%m%d.log
```

Requests **are** being logged to /var/log/freeradius/radius.log:

*Wed Sep 22 16:10:11 2021 : Auth: (0) Login OK: [user1] (from client Switches port 0 cli 8.1.1.1)*

but I want them in a file similar to "/var/log/freeradius/radiusd-DEFAULT-20210922.log"

Is there something I'm missing in the *sites-enables/default* file or something else dumb I've missed?  Thanks!